# Como configurar Jersey 2.22 no projeto?

Tags: java, web-service, jersey

Estou com muita dificuldade para configurar o [Jersey 2.22.1](https://jersey.java.net/) no meu projeto web que é implantado no servidor `Tomcat 8`, que estou desenvolvendo no Netbeans. Obs.: uso o maven.

Já li e reli a [documentação](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html) mas não se encaixa no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

A minha duvida são como configurar os arquivos **`pom.xml`** e **`web.xml`**.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui.

**web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>meu.pacote.dos.recursos</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    ...
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
     ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```